# Maternal Effects

Tags: behaviour, toxicology, epigenetics, predation

Does anyone know of a good review of non-human maternal effects, preferably the most recent? I'm looking for a breakdown of the most well-studied/least studied biotic and abiotic cues. Perhaps something more comprehensive than [Bell & Hellmann (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-ecolsys-110218-024613), with an emphasis on maternal effects as opposed to the more general "transgenerational plasticity".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maternal effects of what sort? I could suggest some social effects of neglect of children by working mothers, but I doubt that you had that in mind. If you define your problem clearly, An internet search will surely provide answers. Any opinions of what constitutes “good” here would be subjective — you need to make your own judgment.

Comment: Also did you tag predation and toxicology for a reason?

Comment: @user438383 Predation and toxicology are two possible environmental cues that can promote maternal effects (see linked paper, table 1). Others include temperature extremes, nutrition quality, in eutero hormone cascades.

Comment: @David I narrowed my question to non-human maternal effects. Regarding what kinds, I am interested in a contemporary review paper, so all possible kinds.

Comment: The word “effects” is meaningless scientifically without saying what is doing the affecting, and what is being affected. Questions here should be self-contained, and I certainly am not going to follow a link to find out what you are talking about. So let’s try again: “Maternal effects of ****** on ****”. You know what you have in mind, but you need to make it clear to us, because we do not.

Comment: @David I am unsure about your field as "biology" is extraordinarily broad. In evolutionary biology, the phrase "maternal effects" has a precise meaning. It is a subset of transgenerational phenotypic plasticity, and a considerable body of literature is associated with it.